# Why can I not assign my items to my object's constant?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I made an object in my chrome extension and added a constant to it

```
const myObj = {};
Object.defineProperty(myObj , "DATABASES", { value:  {}, writable: true, configurable: true });
```

Then I tried to add a value to that constant

```
myObj.DATABASES["key1"] = new Set(
    { a: "aaaa", b: "bbbb" }
);
```

The last line results in the following error, which doesn't make it clear to me which part of the statement is a problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with that last part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` expects an iterable object, like array, and you're passing it an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Syntax

Comment: Ahh, I see. It is not just adding one item to the set! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the syntax with Clarity's link. It should be done as follows:

```
myObj.DATABASES["key1"] = new Set();
myObj.DATABASES["key1"].add({ a: "aaa", b: "bbbb" });
```